# Regular expression in Arabic language

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I want to use a regular expression to accept just the Arabic language

I found this

```
/[\u0600-\u06FF]
```

but it's not working (it accepts all characters )

here is my model

```
[RegularExpression(@"/[\u0600-\u06FF]/$", ErrorMessageResourceType =
typeof(ProcRec.Ressources.Candidat.ErreurValidation),
ErrorMessageResourceName = "nom_ar_faux")]
public string prenom_candidat_arab { set; get; }
```

did I miss somthing ?

Comment: I guess the regex should be `^[\u0600-\u06FF]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the '/' characters for? Looks like Perl Regex syntax.

Try this:

`@"^[\u0600-\u06FF]+$"`

Comment: Please add example strings which should and should not be matched by the regex.

Comment: "car" ==> not matched...........
"محمد" matched...............
"سعيد" matched.....................

Comment: Tested the regex here: http://regexhero.net/tester/ => works as expected. Must be a different problem, maybe with character encoding.

Comment: BTW, check if validation works with a simpler rule (non-regex), like [StringLength(5)]. If not, you have a completely different problem ...

Comment: think you i will try  with the character encoding ......... (the validation works with others regex

Answer (score 3):

You can also simply use [named block character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\p{IsArabic}+$", ErrorMessageResourceType =
typeof(ProcRec.Ressources.Candidat.ErreurValidation),
ErrorMessageResourceName = "nom_ar_faux")]
public string prenom_candidat_arab { set; get; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Arabic you can use this for only Arabic letters

```
^[\u0621-\u064A\040]+$
```

No Numbers